# Get Kerberos tgt on Windows client on C++

Tags: c++, windows, ldap, kerberos

I'm trying to get tgt from Active Directory Server in C++ code. On Linux I use MIT Kerberos library and run `krb5_get_init_creds_password` function. On Windows I want to use some native functions. Do you know analog for `krb5_get_init_creds_password`?

I searched about SSPI, but as I understand documentation, SSPI functions can't get tgt from KDC.

Thank you!

**Edit:** Can somebody tell me please how I can obtain TGT from AD using Windows system commands. Or I should use MIT Kerberos library and use `kinit`? Thx!

Comment: MIT kerberos API works just as well in windows. I have been using it for a long time. However I dont know how to import credential into SSPI. However except for logged in used case - gssapi and mit kerb combo works brilliantly

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should never access the Kerberos 5 API. The user has to obtain the TGT himself (`kinit` or OS login) and you simply use it with GSS-API. Same applies for SSPI.

Comment: no. MIT Kerberos is much more flexible than gssapi and the full power of kerberos comes from direct application. There also exists API which bridges the two

Comment: @ArunavSanyal, which is?

Comment: Well for starters MIT Kerberos API allows fetching of arbitrary TGTs and STs. This can be enormously powerful if you as an application developer dont want extra processes or utilities to do it and is generally a few lines of codes max. Secondly you can access credential caches and check if your tickets are about to expire. This allows you to renew them programatically. Thirdly you can configure parameters like ticket lifetime, options like forwardable(which otherwise need krb5.conf), mutual auth, integrity checks etc. You can customize credential cache as file or memory independent from OS.

Comment: Regarding bridging of gssapi and mit kerberos, an API exists to import kerb creds to GSS creds.